# What is the difference between instantiating using interface and derived class in .net can anyone tell in brief?

Tags: c#

```
interface Icustomer
{
    void sample();
}

public  class customer : Icustomer
{
   public void sample()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("This is sample Method");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       Icustomer ob1 = new customer();
        customer ob2 = new customer();
    }
```

Comment: using interface reference variable `ob1` you can only invoke the interface methods but using `customer` class reference variable `ob2` ,you can invoke all methods declared in `customer` class

Comment: You cannot instantiate an interface.  Your code only ever creates a *customer* class object, the only difference is the type of the variable that you use to store the reference.

Answer (score 3):

For your particular example there is no difference but it is very useful to instantiate against Interface variable as it help in writing concrete instantiation independent code.

For example

```
interface IPizza {    
    public String Bake();  }  

public class CountrySpecial: IPizza   {
     public String Bake() 
     {
      //add country special toppings 
     } }

public class FarmHouse: IPizza   {
     public String Bake()
     { 
     //add farm house special toppings 
     } }

public class Order   {
    public void PlaceOrder(IPizza pizza) 
    {
     pizza.Bake(); 
     //pack and ship 
    } }
```

Now you can do amazing stuff without depending on the concrete initialization, like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
       Order ord = new Order(); 
       //customer ordered for country special
       ord.PlaceOrder(new CountrySpecial()); //this will call bake of CountrySpecial
       //maybe some other customer ordered for different pizza, and we can change at run-time(thanks to our design!)
       ord.PlaceOrder(new FarmHouse()); // this will call Bake of FarmHouse

    }
}
```

With help of above design we can add as many pizza type as we want without ever changing the code for ordering them!

Also, Although you have asked in context of .net but it has nothing to do with language because it's a design question ;)

I hope it may help!

Answer (score 0):

Different ideas. Remember it like this. An interface is a contract so you and other third partys could develop competing services for the same task. A derived class you are using someone else's implementation assuming you're not overriding a virtual.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you only have access to methods and properties that the interface Icustomer declare. In the second case you have access to all methods, properties, fields of customer class.

The real benefit of declaring variable with interface is that you can instance it with any classes which implements it.

Example with this two classes which implements Icustomer interface

```
public class customerA : Icustomer
public class customerB : Icustomer
```

You can instanciate like this for example

```
Icustomer c;
if (test)
    c = new customerA();
else
    c = new customerB();

c.sample();
```

This is the definition of polymorphism